# Bad Connector Shapes In UML Activity Diagram

Tags: visio

I'm using activity diagrams in Visio 2016 but the connectors don't go vertically down properly.

Instead they always do a U-turn unless I offset the shapes from each other. These are set to be straight connectors.

[image: Bad Visio Connectors]

Am I going mad? Is there some way to make the default behaviour straight?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you created the document with a UML sequence diagram template instead of a UML activity diagram template.

In a sequence diagram, vertical arrows are "self calls" so I guess the template sets up all vertical arrows to be this inverted C path